# Skydrive API jpg sizes are not accurate

Tags: api, onedrive

I'm running some tests against Skydrive's API and they're currently failing with .jpg images because the image size communicated back through the API under the 'size' parameter does not match the size of the uploaded file.

Locally before upload the file is 8,250 bytes:

> -rw-r--r--   1 bzittlau  staff   8250 26 Nov 11:41 test_jpg.jpg

After upload Skydrive claims it is 21,137 bytes:

> ["size"]=> int(21137)

After downloading the file it can be seen to still be 8,250 bytes:

> -rw-r--r--@  1 bzittlau  staff   8250 26 Nov 11:51 test_jpg (1).jpg

I have a suspicion that the file size being returned through the API includes the total sizes of all the thumbnails that Skydrive decides to automatically create on the file upload.  What I need is the ability to get the file size of just the full version of the image.  (I know that for images over 2048x2048 this will not work as skydrive will downsize them)

UPDATE: tangential to the original question, but I discovered it's possible to override the 2048 size limitation using the [downsize_photo_uploads=false](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx#photo) request parameter.

Comment: I'm running into same problem for certain png files.